# Android - Put other application on immersive mode from service

Tags: android

Since Kitkat has release, immersive mode (real full screen mode) is widely used and I pretty much love it. I know how to user this feature and how to put my application on immersive mode but I would like to know how to put other running application on immersive mode.

First I created my own service application. The service is supposed to detect another particular application and put it on the immersive mode when it is launched or its activity has changed (change in activity means it needs to be put on immersive mode again)

I am wondering if you think this is possible and need some advice.

(if my post breaks stackoverflow rules please pelase let me know. Don't just block my account, your policy is toooo strict)

Comment: Do you own the "other" application?

Comment: For reference, here are two similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672704/how-can-i-use-persistence-immersive-mode-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512688/full-screen-application-android There may be some hints there

Comment: I do not own the "other" application but there exist some apps that make other apps on immersive mode. Try search "GMD Full Screen"